# Loading two name / value arrays to a new object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm attempting to take two arrays, a column header array:

```
cNames = ["Year","Count"]
```

And a data array:

```
mData  = ["2005",50212,"2006",51520,"2007",52220,"2008",52143]
```

I would like to line the two arrays into a single like so:

```
[
    {
        Year: "2005",
        Count: 50212
    },
    {
        Year: "2006",
        Count: 51520
    },
    {
        Year: "2007",
        Count: 52220
    },
    {
        Year: "2008",
        Count: 52143
    }
]
```

I've tried to load with:

```
var data;
for (var i=0; i < mData.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < cNames.length; j++) {
        data[cNames[j]]=mData[i];
    }
}
```

. . . but I don't get the desired result.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple here . . . Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, I see the need for the temp array now (or reduction). Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

You could use reduce, and push to the array based on the length of the array containing the keys, that way it should work whith arrays with any number of keys and values *(as long as it adds up)*

```js
var cNames = ["Year","Count"]
var mData  = ["2005",50212,"2006",51520,"2007",52220,"2008",52143]

var arr = mData.reduce( (a,b,i) => {
  if (i%cNames.length === 0) 
    a.push(mData.slice(i,cNames.length+i).reduce((c,d,j) => (c[cNames[j]] = d, c),{}));
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it in the following way

```js
let cNames = ["Year","Count"];
let mData  = ["2005",50212,"2006",51520,"2007",52220,"2008",52143];

let i = 0, result = [];
while(i < mData.length){
    let temp = {};
    for(let j=0; j<cNames.length; j++){
        temp[cNames[j]] = mData[i+j];
    }
    result.push(temp);
    i += cNames.length;
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another approach :)

```js
var cNames = ["Year","Count"];
var mData  = ["2005",50212,"2006",51520,"2007",52220,"2008",52143];

var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < mData.length; i+=cNames.length) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var j = 0; j < cNames.length; j++) {
    obj[cNames[j]] = mData[i + j];
  }
  
  output.push(obj);
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, which does the job

```js
cNames = ["Year","Count"];
mData  = ["2005",50212,"2006",51520,"2007",52220,"2008",52143];

var combinedData = [];
var i = 0;
mData.forEach(function(value,index){
 if(i%2==0)
 {
   var itemToPush = {};
   itemToPush[cNames[0]] = value;
   itemToPush[cNames[1]] = mData[index + 1];
   combinedData.push(itemToPush);
 }
 i++;
});

console.log(combinedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cNames = ["Year","Count"];
var mData  = ["2005",50212,"2006",51520,"2007",52220,"2008",52143];

var data = [];
var no_of_attributes = cNames.length; 

while(mData.length > 0)
  {
  var attribute_values = mData.splice(0,no_of_attributes);
  var temp = {};
  for(var i=0; i<no_of_attributes; i++) temp[cNames[i]] = attribute_values[i];
  data.push(temp);
  }

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```